# Random question for random answer in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

can anybody help me to make something like this on Python ?
Example :

```
list = "Back", "Left", "Up"
```

now i want Python to take a random items from the lists above.

If Python take "Back" from the list then the answer is "Front"
If "Up" the answer is "Down"
If "Left" the answer is "Right"

That's all and sorry if it's complicated or not understandable.

Comment: Could you pair them up in tuples, such as `[('Back', 'Front), ('Up', 'Down'), ('Left', 'Right')]`?

Comment: The first thing to note is that you created a _tuple_, not a list. You also trampled over the `builtin` by calling your tuple `list`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `random.choice` like this:

```
import random

questions_answers = [('Back', 'Front'), ('Up', 'Down'), ('Left', 'Right')]
question, answer = random.choice(questions_answers)
print(f"Q: {question}, A: {answer}")
```

Comment: I think i forgot to mention that the answer is the input

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mapping dictionary with your values.

For example:

```
from random import choice

tpl = "Back", "Left", "Up"
mapping = {'Back': 'Front', 'Up': 'Down', 'Left': 'Right'}

v = choice(tpl)
print('Python chose: {}, mapping is {}'.format(v, mapping[v]))
```

Prints:

```
Python chose: Up, mapping is Down
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the python built-in module "random". For this example:

```
import random
myList = ["Back", "Left", "Up"]
random_item_from_list = random.choice(list)
```

Comment: It appears one of the requirements in the original post is to output the opposite of the random choice.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a dictionary. Here's a snippet:

```
import random

mydict = {"back": "front", "left": "right", "up": "down"}

progchoice = random.choice(["back", "left", "up"])
answer = mydict[progchoice]

print(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

import necessary package:

```
import random
```

create input parameters:

```
list_obj = "Back", "Left", "Up"
results_obj = "Front", "Right", "Down"
```

create mapping between lists:

```
mapping = dict(zip(list_obj, results_obj))
```

return the result by randomly chosen key from mapping:

```
mapping[random.choice(list_obj)]
```